# Return two relationship in one resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below are the oversimplified inspired from my production schema.

[image]

Thus, I want to return all these information in one result set.

My desired result set
[image: Desired result]

I have tried this query but it return wrong result.

```
SELECT u.*
    ,f.*
    ,uv.*
    ,v.*
FROM User u
LEFT JOIN UserFarm uf ON uf.UserID = u.ID
LEFT JOIN Farm f ON f.ID = uf.FarmID
LEFT JOIN FarmVehicle fv ON f.ID = fv.FarmID
LEFT JOIN UserVehicle uv ON u.ID = uv.UserID
LEFT JOIN Vehicle v ON fv.VehicleID = v.ID
WHERE u.ID = 1
```

Edit: This is the result from above query.
[image]

Could anyone advise me on this, I really need to return in the desired result.

Comment: Why is result wrong? What is the result you are getting?

Comment: @AB_87 I have updated the result from above query

Comment: Ah, okay, you want to show vehicles and farms even when they are not related.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes correct. Because I want to process the result set into one object later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a query to return the data you want in the first row, and `null` in the columns you don't want for that row.  Then create another query for the second row and use `union all` to combine the data together:

```
declare @UserVehicle table (UserID int, VehicleID int, IsService bit)
declare @User        table (ID int, Name varchar(10))
declare @UserFarm    table (UserID int, FarmID int)
declare @Farm        table (ID int, Name varchar(10))
declare @FarmVehicle table (FarmID int, VehicleID int)
declare @Vehicle     table (ID int, [Type] varchar(10), Name varchar(10))

insert into @UserVehicle values (1, 2, 1)
insert into @User        values (1, 'Sam')
insert into @UserFarm    values (1, 1)
insert into @Farm        values (1, 'Flora')
insert into @FarmVehicle values (1, 1)
insert into @Vehicle     values (1, 'Larry', 'Scania'), (2, 'Unknown', 'Civic')

select [User.ID]               = u.ID
      ,[User.Name]             = u.Name
      ,[Farm.ID]               = f.ID
      ,[Farm.Name]             = f.Name
      ,[UserVehicle.UserID]    = null
      ,[UserVehicle.VehicleID] = null
      ,[UserVehicle.IsService] = null
      ,[Vehicle.ID]            = v.ID
      ,[Vehicle.Name]          = v.Name
from   @User u
       left join @UserFarm uf    on u.ID = uf.UserID
       left join @Farm f         on uf.FarmID = f.ID
       left join @FarmVehicle fv on f.ID = fv.VehicleID
       left join @Vehicle v      on fv.VehicleID = v.ID

union all

select [User.ID]               = u.ID
      ,[User.Name]             = u.Name
      ,[Farm.ID]               = null
      ,[Farm.Name]             = null
      ,[UserVehicle.UserID]    = uv.UserID
      ,[UserVehicle.VehicleID] = uv.VehicleID
      ,[UserVehicle.IsService] = case when uv.IsService = 0 then 'No' else 'Yes' end
      ,[Vehicle.ID]            = v.ID
      ,[Vehicle.Name]          = v.Name
from   @User u
       left join @UserFarm uf    on u.ID = uf.UserID
       left join @UserVehicle uv on u.ID = uv.UserID
       left join @Vehicle v      on uv.VehicleID = v.ID
```

This query returns the following dataset:

```
User.ID     User.Name  Farm.ID     Farm.Name  UserVehicle.UserID UserVehicle.VehicleID UserVehicle.IsService Vehicle.ID  Vehicle.Name
----------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ------------------ --------------------- --------------------- ----------- ------------
1           Sam        1           Flora      NULL               NULL                  NULL                  1           Scania
1           Sam        NULL        NULL       1                  2                     Yes                   2           Civic
```

If you do **not** want to see users who are not assigned to vehicles or farms, then change all `left join` to `inner join`.

Comment: Thank you james, it works. However, this could be a maintenance issue in the long run since I need to make sure columns is in correct order and format. Could we have another solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try with following query

```
    SELECT U.*,T.* FROM (
SELECT F.FARMID,F.NAME AS NAM
    ,UV.*
    ,V.*
FROM VEHICLE V
LEFT JOIN FARMVEHICLE FV ON FV.VEHICLEID = V.ID
LEFT JOIN USERVEHICLE UV ON UV.VEHICLEID = V.ID
LEFT JOIN FARM F ON F.FARMID = FV.FARMID
LEFT JOIN USERFARM UF ON UF.FARMID = F.FARMID)T, USER U
```

Let me know if any issue in query.

Comment: You didn't join `USER` to any of the other data, so the result set will make it look like users are assigned to farms and vehicles to which they are not assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show a user's farms and vehicles. However farms and vehicles can be related, and in that case you want to show them together in a row rather than in separated rows.

Example: User1 is related to Farm1, Farm2, and Farm3 and to Vehicle1, Vehicle2, and Vehicle3. Moreover, Farm1 is related to Vehicle1 and Vehicle2 and Farm2 is also related to Vehicle1.

Then you want:

```
user  | farm  | vehicle
------+-------+---------
User1 | Farm1 | Vehicle1
User1 | Farm1 | Vehicle2
User1 | Farm2 | Vehicle1
User1 | Farm3 | -
User1 | -     | Vehicle3
```

So the second and third columns show the relations of farms with vehicles. You get these with a full outer join. The join's `ON` clause is a bit tricky. You want the `userid` to match and the combination of `farmid` and `vehicleid` to be found in the bridge table `farmvehicle`. Here is one way to do this:

```
with rel as
(
  select coalesce(uf.userid, uv.userid) as userid, uf.farmid, uv.vehicleid
  from userfarm uf
  full outer join uservehicle uv
    on uf.userid = uv.userid
    and exists (select * from farmvehicle fv where fv.farmid = uf.farmid
                                               and fv.vehicleid = uv.vehicleid)
)
select u.name as user_name, f.name as farm_name, v.name as vehicle_name
from usr u
left join rel on u.id = rel.userid
left join farm f on f.id = rel.farmid
left join vehicle v on v.id = rel.vehicleid
order by user_name, farm_name, vehicle_name;
```

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DNKSU25931